# PDF Encoding issue? (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, pdf, encoding, character-encoding, annotations

I'm developing a tool to annotate PDF's and came across what I think is an encoding issue:
When the user tries to save japanese/arabic/russian/etc text into a text annotation, I'm not really sure how save it. I've been encoding it to utf8 and that worked for simple text in english, but if I try to save

日本語注釈のテスト

It ends up like this:

æŠ¥æœ¬èªžæ³¨é⁄‹ã†®ã…ƒã‡¹ã…‹

Has anyone come across a problem like this? I've been struggling with this and trying different encodings for a couple of days but couldn't really reach a solution

Comment: Definitely an encoding issue. Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Updated post with the code I use to create the annotations

Answer (score 1):

You might need to go through the type of NSString Encodings. These are available [japanese encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding)

You should check the type of encoding which the source PDF consists of and accordingly apply your manipulations(encoding/decoding) on it.

Comment: solved it, it was a problem with the communication with the library, it was interpreting it in a different encoding than I was sending :)

Comment: if my answer helped you solving it.. then please accept the answer